# How to provide injection for method which is called in NinjectModule

Tags: c#-4.0, ninject, ninject-2

I have the following `NinjectModule` derived class:

```
class MainModule : NinjectModule 
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>();

        Bind<IMainClass>().To<MainClass>().OnActivation((context,myClass) => 
        { myClass.Add("Something", context.Kernel.Get<IMyClass>());  });
    }
}
```

My problem is that `IKernel` does not exposed the `.Get<T>` extension method.

Is there a pattern for doing this?

Caveats: I don't want to have to decorate my classes with Ninject attributes, as the `Add` is specific to how `MainClass` works I wanted all the code to do with its creation to be held in this module.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, silly oversight in the end it seems.  The extension methods reside in the `Ninject` namespace, using a module only requires that you are `using Ninject.Modules;`

Adding `using Ninject;` meant that the following was possible:

```
Bind<IMainClass>().To<MainClass>()
.OnActivation((context,myClass) => 
{ 
    foreach(var n in context.Kernel.GetAll<IMyClass>())
    {
        myClass.Add("Something", n);  
    }
});
```

I'll leave this open for a bit to see if anyone has a better way of doing this.